# Learning gaussian distribution got confused between two equations

Tags: probability-theory

I'm learning gaussian distributions for Kalman Filter.
In the lecture we were told that to make a new gaussian distribution from 2 given we have the equations:
[image]

But on the other hand there are also these eqations:
[image]

What is difference between those 2?

Comment: There is no difference (except that in the second case we have indices $0,1$ and in the first $1,2$).

Comment: @drhab but in the second image there is a different solution depending on which function is on the right hand side and which is on the left hand side. While in the first image there is no difference.

Comment: I observed that $\mu'=\mu_{new}$ and $\sigma'^2=\sigma_{new}^2$ if in both cases you work with the same indices.